# Eclipse Plugin: Installs correctly, but gives errors on use

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have developed a plugin for Eclipse.  When debugging/testing it through "Launch an application" provided by the IDE it works perfectly, however, when I install it to the host it does not work while it does install correctly.

Errors include:

[image]

[image]

I was wondering if somebody could point me in the correct direction for enabling this plugin to work.

Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in Recognise was unable to load class recognise.handlers.VoiceHandler.
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.loadHandler(HandlerProxy.java:354)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:288)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:252)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:234)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:493)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:486)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:799)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:675)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$7(HandledContributionItem.java:659)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:592)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: recognise.handlers.VoiceHandler cannot be found by Recognise_1.0.0.201603261752
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
... 48 more
```

[image]

Build properties above, I have added way more than necessary, just to make sure that these handlers are in fact added.  Still no change.

Comment: Well Eclipse can't find the `recognise.handlers.VoiceHandler` class referenced in an extension point. Look in the plugin jar to see if it has been included by the plugin build. Show us the `build.properties` file for the plugin.

Comment: There should be a stacktrace with one of the error log entries. Please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Your build.properties should have an entry for '.' in the 'bin.includes' entry:

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/,\
               res/,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               lib/
```

Do **not** include 'bin' in this list.

Comment: Well does the `recognise.handlers.VoiceHandler` class actually exist? Where is it?

Comment: I am new to plugins (my first one) so apologies.  All my handlers are in a package in src/, they also exist in bin/ folder which is included in this build.  Do I need to specify elsewhere ?

Comment: Try starting the Eclipse your are installing the plug-in in with the `-clean` option to be sure it picks up the revised plug-in.